# classification based on image features

Tags: image, class, classification, document-classification

I have around 1000 repository each one contain different number of images, i'm use 20 templates ,then model has been construct for all repositories such that :

each repository contain N number of images ( N is differ from on to other) then for each image it compare with predefined templates (20 templates) if found then 1 otherwise 0 some images my contain more than two template such in image1 where **NBA log** can be found with **Pepsi log** and so on for others .

**my Question** what is model can be used for classifying these repositories  based on pre-defined set of classes with take into consideration my values is binary and each repository contain different number of images?

```
                                  Template-dataset 
repo-ID     image-id         NBA   Pepsi   Cisco-logo .. Spy-cam    class  
Rep1        image1             1    1        0              0        A
Rep1        image2             0    0        0              0        N
....        ......             0    0        0              1        B
Rep2        image1             0    1        0              0        C
```

Comment: Since your classification result are represented as 20-bit binary vectors, I would consider techniques such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance. There is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity.

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus thanks for reply,do you mean i measure similarity between image vectors or document vectors ?